# Ontology for skills

Tags: semantics, ontology

I am looking for a skill ontology, specifically related to skills related to computer science. The ontology should have a similarity mapping for e.g:

> Core Java <==> J2SE

I came across a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506502/ontological-databases-for-professions-and-skills) but the answers were more about tools to create a new ontology.